# Populate table from 2 data sets. Add data data in same td

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, html-table

I am trying to populate a table from 2 data sets.

I can successfully populate it from one data set. I don't want to append the data from the 2nd data set(data2). I want to add the data in the same `td`'s below the data from `data1`. I have created 2 divs inside each td. The first div should contain data from data1. How do I add data from data2 to the 2nd div?

This is how I populated the table and further the first div:

```js
let data1 = [
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:11, val2:22, val3:33},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:25, val2:27, val3:28},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:80, val3:15},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:12, val2:21, val3:31},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:26, val2:16, val3:11},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:65, val2:79, val3:55},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:17, val2:19, val3:11},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:13, val2:15, val3:12},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:69, val2:79, val3:15},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:17, val2:51, val3:31},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:25, val2:15, val3:17},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:61, val2:71, val3:15}
  ];

  let data2 = [
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:30, val2:10, val3:20},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:22, val3:17},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:97, val2:88, val3:15},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:80, val2:30, val3:39},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:26, val2:22, val3:17},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:57, val2:88, val3:15},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:41, val2:32, val3:35},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:26, val2:37, val3:29},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:47, val2:90, val3:17},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:22, val2:31, val3:33},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:25, val2:26, val3:13},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:75, val2:89, val3:57},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:27, val2:99, val3:13},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:53, val2:45, val3:15},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:39, val2:99, val3:17},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:16, val2:31, val3:33},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:29, val2:25, val3:19},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:71, val2:91, val3:17}
  ];

Object.keys(data1[0]).forEach(heads => $(`#my_ths`).append(`<th>${heads}</th>`));
  let ths = Object.keys(data1[0]);

  data1.forEach(d => {
    $(`#my_tds`).append(`<tr></tr>`);
    ths.forEach(th => {
        $(`#my_tds > tr:last`).append(`
            <td>
            <div class='one'>${d[th]}</div>
            <div class='two'></div>
            </td>
            `);
    });
});
```

```css
table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
#mytable { 
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='mytable'>
  <thead><tr id='my_ths'></tr></thead>
  <tbody id='my_tds'></tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I am able to populate `div.one`. How do I populate `div.two` with data from data2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second parameter to [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to index into the `data2` array and get the corresponding values to the `data1` ones using:

```js
data2[idx][th]
```

```js
let data1 = [
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {date:'2018-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:11, val2:22, val3:33},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:25, val2:27, val3:28},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:80, val3:15},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:12, val2:21, val3:31},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:26, val2:16, val3:11},
  {date:'2018-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:65, val2:79, val3:55},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:17, val2:19, val3:11},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:13, val2:15, val3:12},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:69, val2:79, val3:15},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:17, val2:51, val3:31},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:25, val2:15, val3:17},
  {date:'2018-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:61, val2:71, val3:15}
  ];

  let data2 = [
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:30, val2:10, val3:20},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:23, val2:22, val3:17},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:97, val2:88, val3:15},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:80, val2:30, val3:39},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:26, val2:22, val3:17},
  {date:'2017-01-01', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:57, val2:88, val3:15},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:41, val2:32, val3:35},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:26, val2:37, val3:29},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:47, val2:90, val3:17},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:22, val2:31, val3:33},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:25, val2:26, val3:13},
  {date:'2017-01-02', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:75, val2:89, val3:57},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:27, val2:99, val3:13},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'bing',   val1:53, val2:45, val3:15},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'iphone',   site: 'jeeves', val1:39, val2:99, val3:17},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'google', val1:16, val2:31, val3:33},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'bing',   val1:29, val2:25, val3:19},
  {date:'2017-01-03', device: 'ipad',     site: 'jeeves', val1:71, val2:91, val3:17}
  ];

Object.keys(data1[0]).forEach(heads => $(`#my_ths`).append(`<th>${heads}</th>`));
  let ths = Object.keys(data1[0]);

  data1.forEach((d, idx) => {
    $(`#my_tds`).append(`<tr></tr>`);
    ths.forEach(th => {
        $(`#my_tds > tr:last`).append(`
            <td>
            <div class='one'>${d[th]}</div>
            <div class='two'>${data2[idx][th]}</div>
            </td>
            `);
    });
});
```

```css
table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
#mytable { 
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='mytable'>
  <thead><tr id='my_ths'></tr></thead>
  <tbody id='my_tds'></tbody>
</table>
```